# Cannot add custom source_model into widget

Tags: magento-1.9

I tried to add new custom source_model (select).
My config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pixels_UniversalPixel>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Pixels_UniversalPixel>
    </modules>

    <global>
      <models>
         <universal_pixel>
            <class>Pixels_UniversalPixel_Model</class>
         </universal_pixel>
      </models>
    </global>

</config>
```

My widget.xml:

```
<widgets>
    <universal_pixel type="universal_pixel/pixel">
        <name>Universal Pixel</name>
        <description type="desc">Adds a universal pixel</description>
        <parameters>
            <require_consent>
                <label>Require consent</label>
                <type>select</type>
                <required>1</required>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <value>1</value>
                <source_model>universal_pixel/system_config_source_gdpr_states</source_model>
            </require_consent>
        </parameters>
    </universal_pixel>
</widgets>
```

And my model src/app/code/local/Pixels/UniversalPixel/Model/System/Config/Source/GDPR/States.php :

```
<?php

class Pixels_UniversalPixel_Model_System_Config_Source_GDPR_States
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'value' => 0,
                'label' => 'No consent',
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 1,
                'label' => 'Require consent',
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 2,
                'label' => 'Require consent in EU only',
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Where is my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is right except the directory name you are using:

Change the directory name from GDPR to Gdpr and also change the class name from:

```
class Pixels_UniversalPixel_Model_System_Config_Source_GDPR_States
```

to

```
class Pixels_UniversalPixel_Model_System_Config_Source_Gdpr_States
```